# How to pass index of an array without hardcoding to update method of 'react-addons-update'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability

```
nameChangedHandler = (id, event) => {
    let index = id;
    const updatedName = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
      persons: update(this.state.persons, { index: { name: { $set: updatedName } } }),
    });
  };
```

If I hardcode the index to any number the above code is working i.e ( `update(this.state.persons, { 0: { name: { $set: updatedName } } })` )

Kindly Suggest a Solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`computed property`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) to use the value of the `index` variable:

```
this.setState({
  persons: update(this.state.persons, { [index]: { name: { $set: updatedName } } }),
});
```

Comment: Why only index we have to pass as computed property why not updatedName?

Comment: @AravindVijayan The right hand side of `{ key: value }` will always be the value of that variable.

Answer (score 2):

replace `{ index: ... }` with `{ [index]: ... }`